# How can I split DataFrame into two different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have below CSV file

```
timestamp,store,customer_name,basket_items,total_price,cash_or_card,card_number
06/06/2022 09:00,Chesterfield,Stephanie Neyhart,"Large Flat white - 2.45, Large Flavoured iced latte - Vanilla - 3.25, Large Flavoured iced latte - Hazelnut - 3.25",8.95,CASH,
```

I want to split `basket_items` like

```
product                                   price 
Large Flat white                          2.45
Large Flavoured iced latte - Vanilla      3.25
Large Flavoured iced latte - Hazelnut     3.25
```

How can I do that with pandas dataframe?

Comment: If i understand, you want to create a dataframe with 2 columns witch have the information about the products in basket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```py
#data
df = pd.DataFrame([{'timestamp': '06/06/2022 09:00',
                    'store': 'Chesterfield',
                    'customer_name': 'Stephanie Neyhart',
                    'basket_items': "Large Flat white - 2.45, Large Flavoured iced latte - Vanilla - 3.25, Large Flavoured iced latte - Hazelnut - 3.25",
                    'total_price': 8.95,
                    'cash_or_card': 'CASH'}])
# split by comma and explode (to separate products into multi-rows)
# split by dash once from the right side to separate product from price
res = df.basket_items.str.split(', ').explode().str.rsplit(' - ', n=1, expand=True)
# set column names
res.columns = ['product', 'price']
res
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

def extract_prods(row):
    return [
        {key:val.strip() for key, val in zip(['product', 'price'], prod.rsplit('-', 1))}
        for prod in row.split(', ')
    ]

pd.DataFrame(sum(df['basket_items'].apply(extract_prods), []))
```

| product | price |
| --- | --- |
| Large Flat white | 2.45 |
| Large Flavoured iced latte - Vanilla | 3.25 |
| Large Flavoured iced latte - Hazelnut | 3.25 |
| Large Flat white | 2.45 |
| Large Flavoured iced latte - Vanilla | 3.25 |
| Large Flavoured iced latte - Hazelnut | 3.25 |